# Linq how to union array of objects inside list and group by value

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a problem and need some help. I've got a list of objects which have many properties, but only two are important "From" and "To".

objectData { "From" : "ContactDTO", "To" : ["ContactDTO"], ...//other fields }

contactDto { "email" : "string", ... other fields }

and I need to return new list with unique entries "From", array of contacts "To" without duplicates.

Test Data:

```
{ 
   "From": { "email" : "user1@test.com"}, 
   "To": "[{ "email" : "user2@test.com"}, { "email" : "user3@test.com"}]"
},
{ 
   "From": { "email" : "user1@test.com"}, 
   "To": "[{ "email" : "user3@test.com"}, { "email" : "user4@test.com"}]"
},
{ 
   "From": { "email" : "user2@test.com"}, 
   "To": "[{ "email" : "user4@test.com"}, { "email" : "user5@test.com"}]"
},
```

Should Return:

```
[
"From": { "email" : "user1@test.com"}, 
   "To": "[{ "email" : "user2@test.com"}, { "email" : "user3@test.com"}, { "email" : "user4@test.com"}]"
{ 
   "From": { "email" : "user2@test.com"}, 
   "To": "[{ "email" : "user4@test.com"}, { "email" : "user5@test.com"}]"
}
]
```

I know how to do it in a loop, but I would like to make it more readable and clean with using linq.

I've tried:

```
var newData = data.Where(x => IsReview(x))
                .Select(x => 
                new { 
                    From = x.From.EmailAddress, 
                    List = x.To.Select(z => z.EmailAddress).ToList() 
                }).GroupBy(y => y.From);
```

Comment: What issue you faced in your attempt? Do you want unique email addresses in `List`?

Comment: Well u r almost there, try adding select to groupby. Inside select apply selectmany to flatten the emails followed by distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *Select* new object after *GroupBy* and use [**SelectMany**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to flatten emails in one list, like the following code:

```
var newData = data.Where(x => IsReview(x))
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        From = x.From.EmailAddress, 
        List = x.To.Select(z => z.EmailAddress).ToList() 
    }).GroupBy(y => y.From)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        From = x.Key,
        To = x.SelectMany(y => y.List).ToList()
    });
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: thank you for your help, I've modified it a bit, but manage to get it working. I'm marking your answer as correct one, have a great day.

Comment: you're welcome, was glad to help, have a good day too.